# okhttp3 RequestBody in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp

I want to send a request body like this :

### How I send this ? I will send it as a class ?

```
"email":{
    "emailto":"foo@bar.com",
    "emailfrom":"foo@bar.com",
    "emailcc":"foo@bar.com",
    "emailbcc":"foo@bar.com",
    "emailsubject":"Subject",
    "emailtag":"Information",
    "emailtextbody":"---",
    "attachments":[]
}
```

---

```
val formBody = FormBody.Builder()
    .add("email", "Your message")
    .build()

val request = Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .post(formBody)
    .addHeader("_Token","")
    .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
    .build()
```

Comment: what seems to be the issue, it looks like there should be no issue sending the JSON as is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I highly suggest to use [Retofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) for such case, but if you really need to deal with raw `Request`/`Response` then your solution looks like:

```
val json = """
"email":{
    "emailto":"${emailto}",
    "emailfrom":"${emailfrom}",
    "emailcc":"${emailcc}",
    "emailbcc":"${emailbcc}",
    "emailsubject":"${emailsubject}",
    "emailtag":"${emailtag}",
    "emailtextbody":"${emailtextbody}",
    "attachments":[]
}
""".trimIndent()

val body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json)
val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build()
```

Just pass parameters in brackets (e.g. `${emailto}`) to your function.

In case, if you don't want to build json manually, you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library.

```
data class EmailInfo(
        val emailto: String,
        val emailfrom: String,
        val emailcc: String,
        val emailbcc: String,
        val emailsubject: String,
        val emailtag: String,
        val emailtextbody: String,
        val attachments: List<Attachment>
)

data class EmailRequest(
        val email: EmailInfo
)

...

val emailRequest = EmailRequest(
        email = EmailInfo(
                emailto = "...",
                emailfrom = "...",
                emailcc = "...",
                emailbcc = "...",
                emailsubject = "...",
                emailtag = "...",
                emailtextbody = "...",
                attachments = ...
        )
)

val json = Gson().toJson(emailRequest)

val body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json)
val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. The first part works for me. I ll try the second answer in complicated project

Answer (score 11):

For more clarity on the answer given above, this is how you can use the extension functions.

If you are using `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1` the older methods of creating objects of **MediaType** and **RequestBody** have been deprecated and cannot be used in *Kotlin*.

If you want to use the extension functions to get a **MediaType** object and a **ResponseBody** object from your strings, firstly add the following lines to the class in which you expect to use them.

```
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody
```

You can now directly get an object of **MediaType** this way

```
val mediaType = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()
```

To get an object of **RequestBody** first convert the JSONObject you want to send to a string this way. You have to pass the mediaType object to it.

```
val requestBody = myJSONObject.toString().toRequestBody(mediaType)
```

Comment: Are there any pre-defined MediaType constants instead of copy-pasting from project to project? For example this one "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: I haven't found a way to do that yet. I think there should be a way. I'll post here if I find a way.