# Send JSON data using OkHttp using Kotlin

Tags: java, json, kotlin, okhttp

I am trying to send JSON data to the server using the OKhttp library and having trouble figuring out the right syntax for it. Tried the solution provided in this post [okhttp3 RequestBody in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395067/okhttp3-requestbody-in-kotlin?answertab=active#tab-top) The class is deprecated as of now.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln6rq.png)

Comment: Please post your code, not an image, and read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You can check may be this is solve in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58380502/11811105)

Answer (score 9):

For more clarity on the answer given above, this is how you can use the extension functions.

If you are using `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1` the older medthods of creating objects of **MediaType** and **RequestBody** have been deprecated and cannot be used in *Kotlin*.

If you want to use the extension functions to get a **MediaType** object and a **ResponseBody** object from your strings, firstly add the following lines to the class in which you expect to use them.

```
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody
```

You can now directly get an object of **MediaType** this way

```
val mediaType = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()
```

To get an object of **RequestBody** first convert the JSONObject you want to send to a string this way. You have to pass the mediaType object to it.

```
val requestBody = myJSONObject.toString().toRequestBody(mediaType)
```

Comment: What can I do if "Companion" turns read trying to use this import?

Answer (score 6):

you need to create an object of type okhttp3.Request.Builder and add okhttp3.RequestBody via the post method

```
val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = ...
//val httpUrl = HttpUrl.parse("string url") ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("wrong url $url")//3.12.1
val httpUrl = "string url".toHttpUrl()//4.0.1
val httpUrlBuilder = httpUrl.newBuilder()
val requestBuilder = Request.Builder().url(httpUrlBuilder.build())
//val mediaTypeJson = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8") ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("wrong media type")//3.12.1
val mediaTypeJson = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()//4.0.1
val jsonString = "{\"jsondata\":0}"
requestBuilder.post(
jsonString.toRequestBody(mediaTypeJson)//4.0.1
//RequestBody.create(mediaTypeJson, jsonString)//3.12.1
)
val call = okHttpClient.newCall(requestBuilder.build())
... = call.execute()
```

Comment: Gives me the following error  Using 'parse(String): MediaType?' is an error. moved to extension function

Comment: Of course, you need to handle the fact that the parse method can return `null`. Corrected the answer.

Comment: requestBuilder.post(RequestBody.create(
    MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8")!!,
    "{\"jsondata\":0}")  . Gives an error that -  Using 'parse(String): MediaType?' is an error. moved to extension function

Comment: Are you using `implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3: okhttp: 3.12.1'`? I updated the answer.

Comment: I am using     implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1"
I cannot figure out how to create the RequestBody Parameter that is required in the post method.

Comment: I found out an updated method to form the requestBody using String.toRequestBody() but just could not figure out the way to use it https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-request-body/to-request-body/

Comment: fixed the answer for version 4.0.1

Comment: It still shows an error that RequestBody.create method is deprecated

Comment: fixed the answer for version 4.0.1 (toRequestBody)

Comment: Got it working now. The issue was that the Android Studio was not importing the Compact.toRequestBody() had to manually import it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your build.gradle inside your dependencies, make sure you are using

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1"
}
```

Then, do a sync and the Android Studio IDE will offer you

```
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
```

After this you'll be able to

```
val contentType = "application/json".toMediaType()
```