# Okhttp3 - RequestBody.create(contentType, content) Deprecated

Tags: java, okhttp

I did not find any example of how to replace the deprecation method.
The examples on the okhttp3 main page are old.
This is one of them:

```
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
      Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(url)
          .post(body)
          .build();
  try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    return response.body().string();
  }
}
```

If someone could solve it, I would appreciate your help.

Update:
     I'm using 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1'

Comment: It doesn't seem to be deprecated: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/RequestBody.html#create-okhttp3.MediaType-java.lang.String-

Comment: I'm using 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1', and every suggestion in this SO and others I've searched for the last 2 hours all are depreciated, or cannot be resolved by the IDE.  I've tried importing libraries manually and any other suggestion that I can find on SO and in the okHttp documentation, not thing works.
I can't believe that something so widely used is sooo hard to use.
If there is anyone out there who can help (Jake?) I just need to call api with a blank postBody.

In Postman, it is called like "post(null)"

Thanks for any suggestions anyone has in advanced.

Answer (score 197):

**Java Solution:**
Use `create(String, MediaType)` instead of `create(MediaType, String)` for example

**Kotlin Solution:**
Use the extension function `content.toRequestBody(contentType)`;
for the File type `file.asRequestBody(contentType)`

**Note:**
I'm using kotlin, but my IDE just doesn't automatically import the class or method like `import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody`, so I import it manually...then use it as the example given by [Saeed Younus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58380502/11136727) and [Pratyesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493066/11136727) below

**For more:** The documentation

(In Android Studio or any Jetbrain's IDE, the solution to the deprecated methods or class can be found by just holding the **Ctrl** and clicking on the `create(...)` of `RequestBody.create`)

Comment: need to import manually
*okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.asRequestBody* to use *file.asReqestBody* and *okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody* to use *content.toRequestBody*

Comment: @YuTang what is content in content.RequestBody? Does this mean I can pass content:// uri?

Comment: @Sudhir Khanger the content string can be anything you want to post to the back server-side, like JSON.

Comment: for such generic deprecation android studio or intellij should just have a button of fix - rather than only suppress...

Comment: Like what DragonFire said, when your IDE is android studio or intellij. just to locate the cursor on the deprecated fuction, and use ```Alt``` + ```Enter```, choose the fix option, I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 48):

In com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.1.0

`MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8")` no more available.

instead this we need to use `"application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull()`.

For example how we need to create request body now since `okhttp:4.1.0`

```
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaTypeOrNull
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody

    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
        jsonObject.put("name", "Ancd test")
        jsonObject.put("city", "delhi")
        jsonObject.put("age", "23")
    val body = jsonObject.toString().toRequestBody("application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull())
```

**To those wondering where the answers are coming from!**

All the alternatives/solutions(as described by the answer) are documented in the **corresponding deprecated code**! Just manoeuvre to it (the deprecated code) using whichever means your IDE supports. ***For example***, to see the alternative/solution to the deprecated code `RequestBody.create(...,...)` when using **AndroidStudio** or any **Jetbrain's IDE**, just long-press `Ctrl` and hover over the `RequestBody.create(...,...)` then click on it when it's hovered over successfully

Comment: I wish this would auto-import

Answer (score 24):

You need to import these files manually may be this is a bug in android studio. It is not suggested but this is work for Okhttp 4.2.2

```
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaTypeOrNull
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.asRequestBody
```

and use as

```
val file = File("path")
file.asRequestBody("image/jpeg".toMediaTypeOrNull())
```

Comment: could you please help me to implement this code in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744692/how-to-upload-image-in-latest-retrofit-version-using-kotlin-with-the-right-reque ?

Answer (score 12):

It was deprecated since [version 4.0.0 of okhttp3](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-4.0.0/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/RequestBody.kt#L167).

The documentation for that version says

```
@JvmStatic
    @Deprecated(
        message = "Moved to extension function. Put the 'content' argument first to fix Java",
        replaceWith = ReplaceWith(
            expression = "content.toRequestBody(contentType)",
            imports = ["okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody"]
        ),
        level = DeprecationLevel.WARNING)
    fun create(contentType: MediaType?, content: String) = content.toRequestBody(contentType)
```

I haven't tried it but I believe that you should be good by doing the following:

```java
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class Test {

  public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");


  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }

  String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    //RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.Companion.create(json, JSON);

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();
    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
      return response.body().string();
    }
  }

}
```

**Update:** I tried to compile the file shown above using the following dependency version and `RequestBody.Companion.create(json, JSON)` doesn't seem to be deprecated.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks jlmayorga, but also RequestBody.Companion.create(json, JSON) is deprecated. And "import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody" cannot be resolved.

Comment: Can you please update your question with information about the dependency version that you use?

Comment: Yes, I have just done it.  I'm using 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.1'

Comment: Don't import the method ``import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody`` just import ``RequestBody`` as in the sample that I provided and you should be good.

Comment: I could solve it, I was using create(MediaType, String) "deprecated", instead of create(String, MediaType). Thank you jlmayorga.

Answer (score 7):

Can u update like that

```
val apiRequest = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain;charset=utf-8"), "edit_group")
val tokenRequest = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain;charset=utf-8"), token)
val fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file)
```

to

```
val apiRequest = "edit_group".toRequestBody("text/plain;charset=utf-8".toMediaType())
val tokenRequest = token.toRequestBody("text/plain;charset=utf-8".toMediaType())
val file = File(path)
val fileReqBody = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaType())
```

Comment: This contribution saved my day! thanks so much bro.

Comment: Best answer. Should be the accepted

Answer (score 4):

Just change `ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/json"), plainBody.trim())`
to `ResponseBody.create(plainBody.trim(),MediaType.parse("text/json"))`

Answer (score 3):

Just had a quick look at the documentation . It reads deprecated, however the alternative is provided in the doc.
json.toRequestBody(contentType) should do the trick for you.
Below is the documentation link:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/RequestBody.kt

```
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.Companion.create(json, JSON)
      Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(url)
          .post(body)
          .build();
  try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    return response.body().string();
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, the json variable is a String and doesn't have the toRequestBody method

Comment: Sorry was thinking in Kotlin. In java it would be a static function imported from the package.

Comment: @jlmayorga : You were right. Upvoting you answer as mine is a duplicate

Comment: Provided url is broken

Comment: I would recommend to combine it with an enum like org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.name or a constant like spring org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

Answer (score 1):

ok according to okhttp 4 many thing updated as official docs

RequestBody.create() is upgraded to File.asRequestBody()

Answer (score 1):

You Just Need To Flip Your Args.

@kotlin.jvm.JvmStatic @kotlin.Deprecated public final fun create(contentType: okhttp3.MediaType?, file: java.io.File): okhttp3.RequestBody { }

```
    @kotlin.jvm.JvmStatic @kotlin.Deprecated @kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads public final fun create(contentType: okhttp3.MediaType?, content: kotlin.ByteArray, offset: kotlin.Int , byteCount: kotlin.Int): okhttp3.RequestBody {}

    @kotlin.jvm.JvmStatic @kotlin.Deprecated public final fun create(contentType: okhttp3.MediaType?, content: kotlin.String): okhttp3.RequestBody {}

    @kotlin.jvm.JvmStatic @kotlin.Deprecated public final fun create(contentType: okhttp3.MediaType?, content: okio.ByteString): okhttp3.RequestBody { }
```