# how to upload image in latest retrofit version using Kotlin with the right RequestBody.create method?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have tried to read the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100451/okhttp3-requestbody-createcontenttype-content-deprecated/58380502#58380502) or in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100451/okhttp3-requestbody-createcontenttype-content-deprecated/57493066#57493066) , but I am confused when I implement it on my own code

I am using this on my gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.0'
```

I am trying to upload an image using this code in retorift

```
interface UploadMediaAPI {

    @Multipart
    @POST("uploadImage")
    fun uploadImage(
        @Part image: MultipartBody.Part
    ): Call<UploadResponse>


}
```

and use it like this

```
val fileImagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imageFile", file.name, RequestBody.create("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file))
val call = uploadMediaAPI.uploadImage(image = fileImagePart)

call.enqueue(object : Callback<UploadResponse> {


    override fun onResponse(call: Call<UploadResponse>, response: Response<UploadResponse>) {

    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<UploadResponse>, t: Throwable) {

    }

})
```

the problem is, the RequestBody.create is deprecated
[image]

it is said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58380502/9605341) , I have to use the code below to change the deprecated method

```
val file = File("path")
file.asRequestBody("image/jpeg".toMediaTypeOrNull())
```

but I am really confused how to put this code in my own code

could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
val file = File(FileUtil.getPath(this, <your_uri>)) // get file from uri
val requestFile = file.asRequestBody(contentResolver.getType(<your_uri>)?.toMediaTypeOrNull())
val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imageFile", file.name, requestFile)
val call = uploadMediaAPI.uploadImage(image = body)

call.enqueue(object: Callback<UploadResponse> {

  override fun onResponse(call: Call<UploadResponse>, response: Response<UploadResponse>) {
  }

  override fun onFailure(call: Call<UploadResponse>, t: Throwable) {
  }
})
```

For more information please check [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server).

Answer (score 0):

For me I have resolved in this way and its working fine:

```
val filePhoto = File(strPhotoUrl) //For example "/storage path
val photoBody = filePhoto.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
var partPhoto = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imageFile", filePhoto.name, photoBody)
```